# Add id to each element based on the count in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div class="tile_nav">
<ul>
<li><span class="ullevel2"><span>Sample text</span></span></li>
<li><span class="ullevel2"><span>Sample text</span></span></li>
<li><span class="ullevel2"><span>Sample text</span></span></li>
<li><span class="ullevel2"><span>Sample text</span></span></li>        
</ul>   
</div>


I have used

$(".tile_nav .ullevel2 span").attr('id', function(index) {
return "testDiv" + ($(this).index() + 1);
});
```

How to add id to each element based on the length by jQuery each on page loading?

Comment: `$('.span_group span').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('id', 'span' + $.trim($(this).text()));
});`

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?

Answer (score 0):

You may use:

```
$('.span_group span').attr('id', function(idx){
    return 'span'+ idx;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through all element and add id to each

```js
$(".span_group").children().each(function(index){
   this.id = "span"+(index+1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="span_group">
<span>1</span>
<span>2</span>
<span>3</span>
<span>4</span>
<span>5</span>
</div>
```

Comment: this.id = "span"+$(this).text().trim();    instead of text()  i need current number/length of element

Comment: @AnoopPranav Made the changes

Answer (score 0):

The selector here `$('.span_group span')` will return a collection of tag names of `span` in the parent block of `.span_group` so you just have to set the attribute to the spans inside `.span_group`.

In the `.attr()` we can use a function as a second param to return a value.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.span_group span').attr('id', function() {
    return 'span' + ($(this).index()+1);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="span_group">
  <span>1</span>
  <span>2</span>
  <span>3</span>
  <span>4</span>
  <span>5</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use :

```
$(".span_group span").each(function(index){
    $(this).attr("id","span"+$(this).text());
});
```

See the fiddle:"http://jsfiddle.net/sraq9qj9/"

Explanation: It will iterate over each `span` of element having class `.span_group` and will assign `id` to it using `attr('id',someValue)`. Here `someValue` is the text of the `span` itself since `$this` refer to the current element object(span in this case).